# I can't understand how to pass parameters from activity to custom view

Tags: android, parameter-passing, android-custom-view

I'm new to programming on android and I can't understand how to pass parameters between an activity and a custom view.
My activity only implements the custom view, I use a getter method in the custom view to pass a string. The string is used to set the player's name in a text view.
Printing the string in the setPlayerName method seems to be passed correctly but in reality when I go to execute the changeTurn () method the variable mPlayerName is null. I can't understand why.

This is my activity

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GameMap gameMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        gameMap = new GameMap(this, "MYNAME");
        gameMap.setPlayerName("MYNAME");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    }
}
```

This is my custom view

```
public class GameMap extends RelativeLayout {
    private String mPlayerName;
    private TextView tv;
    private int turn;


    public GameMap(Context context, String playerName) {
        super(context);
        init(context,playerName);
    }

    public GameMap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, String playerName) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, playerName);
    }

    public GameMap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, String playerName) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, playerName);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public GameMap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes, String playerName) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, playerName);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        View rootView = inflate(context,R.layout.game_custom_layout,this);
        tv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.turno);
        turn = 0;
        if(turn == 0) {
            //here mPLayerName is null
            tv.setText(mPlayerName);
        }
        else {
            tv.setText("CPU");
        }

        createMap();
    }


    private void createMap(){
        //I don't change mPLayerName here.
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName){
        this.mPlayerName = playerName;
        System.out.println("string " + playerName + "mPLayerName " +mPlayerName);
        //here playerName and mPlayerName are not null but there is the correct string
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //draw the map, don't edit mPlayerName
    }



    private void changeTurn(){
        if(turn == 0) {
            turn = 1;
            tv.setText("CPU");

        }
        else {
            turn = 0;
            System.out.println("player name " + mPlayerName);
            tv.setText(mPlayerName); 
            //here mPlayerName is null
        }
    }

    private void movePlayer(int x, int y, float newX, float newY){
      if(/*a specific condition */){
        invalidate();
        return;
      }
      changeTurn();
      invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            movePlayer(cellX, cellY, newX, newY);
            return true;
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            return false;

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

I have modified the constructors code and the error message I receive is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.game.project, PID: 24310
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.game.project/com.game.project.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.crossthebox.progetto.GameMap
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.game.project.GameMap
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.game.project.GameMap
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2327)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:615)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.game.project.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:22) // this is setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

this is the layout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">


    <com.game.project.GameMap
        android:id="@+id/gameMapView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide the code where you try to call changeTurn() ?

Comment: Where are you calling `changeTurn()`, and how are you actually inflating the `GameMap` custom view?

Comment: @joshuadeguzman changeTurn() is called inside movePlayer() and how I inflate the gameMap is in init() method

Answer (score 0):

In your `init` method, you call `mPlayerName` variable before `mPlayerName` got set, so it gives you a null `String`.

To solve it, you can create a constructor that accepts another param which is `playerName`.

```
public GameMap(Context context, String playerName) {
    super(context);
    mPlayerName = playerName;
    init(context);
}
```

With the above code, your `mPlayerName` will be set before the `init` method called, so the `tv` will set a correct `String` value.

Comment: what happens with all the other constructors by adding the String playerName parameter to each constructor? however in this way the activity crashes on setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

Comment: Can you post the entire constructor? Also, copy the crash log here so probably I can know what is causing the error.

Comment: I have modified the constructors code and the error message I receive is at the bottom

Comment: It seems that your `R.layout.activity_game` layout is causing the error. Please post the layout.

Comment: layout posted at the bottom

Comment: I'm sorry but I really can't help you further. What I know so far is your `com.game.project.GameMap` is causing the `setContentView` problem. And you should set the player name from the constructor.